# Importing a function library into a script from another folder fails (but works in a Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, python-import

I have read many posts about importing packages and modules, with absolute and relative syntax, but I cannot make it import the functions I need (I'm not a Python expert). I work with VSCode (in Ubuntu) and have a repository structure with Jupyter notebooks in one folder and scripts in another like this:

```
data/
model_notebooks/
└── model_nb.ipynb
src/
└── myutils.py
```

I can import functions from `myutils.py` into the notebook by changing the current working directory at the beginning of the notebook and then importing the functions I need:

```
import os
os.chdir('../src/')

from myutils import data_load
```

This also works when importing a whole `.py` library, not just a function.

I am now trying to export those notebooks into scripts but I am having trouble importing the functions. The repository structure has changed a bit:

```
data/
src/
└── myutils.py
└── model_scripts/
    └── model.py
```

I can only make it work if I place `model.py` and `myutils.py` in the same folder (at the same level), for example in `src/` (without changing the cwd in the script).

As far as I understand when executing the script from the console the current working repository does not depend on the file path but the console path from which I run the script, so it doesn't work when executing

`repo_root$ python src/model_scripts/model.py` with `os.chdir('../src/')` in the script.

But if I execute it within `src/` with

`repo_root/src$ python model_scripts/model.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myutils'`.

I have also tried with relative importing with no luck. It has to run on different systems and it should work independently of the current path in the console. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure both src/ and model_scripts/ have the file `__init__.py`
2. At the start of your model.py, add:

> import sys

> import os

> sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), '..')))

> from myutils import data_load

3. To run your script, stand outside (in repo_root/) and execute:

> python src/model_scripts/model.py

Comment: Thanks! I tried previously with `__init__.py` but it didn't work. It's working now but using `__file__` instead of `file` in `sys.path.append()`. It is also working even if executing the script from inside `src/` folder with `python model_scripts/model.py`.